# The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' vsts build

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have one big solution which contains multiple projects.
like that:

main.sln

```
-ProjectA_api.proj  
-ProjectA_BL.proj  
-ProjectA_Common.proj  

-Project B....etc
```

api consumes BL, BL consumes common.
All of them consume nuget packages.

The main solution has a Nuget.Config file that describes where all the packages are stored.
When I run local build from vs2017 on the ProjectA_api.proj, everything finishes correctly. And I can publish the ProjectA_api.proj to the web.
I try to automate this process using VSTS build service (My end goal is to publish to Azure web App).

It looks like that:

[image]
**Get Sources task** gets all the relevant sources for this build:
Nuget.Config file from sln, and all the project (API, BL,COMMON).
**Restore Nuget task** has the following settings:

- "Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json" = path to the ProjectA_api.proj package.json file

  - Path to nuget config file = main.sln nuget.config file
    **Build solution task** - has the path to ProjectA_api.proj proj file

When I run this process, the restore is fine, and msbuild works for a while, until I get error:
"Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" for the "ProjectA_Common.proj" (ProjectA_common.proj uses 3 references, one of them is azure reference).

All of the solution packages are contained in the solution level packages folder. I also tried to add nuget restore for all the projects, but still the same error. Is it possible to complete my goal this way, or should I make single solution for only these projects (I don't want to do that)?
Thanks

**Edit**
In projectA_common I have the correct packages.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.12" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I tried to change the targetFramework but it didn't work. Also noticed that other packages were OK.

**Edit 2 - Nuget.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
      <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**Reference inside common.proj file**

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.3.2.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Did you make sure the `packages.config` for `*ProjectA_Common*` has the Azure NuGet referring like  `<package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net47" />`

Comment: Yes. Just added it to the original post. thanks

Comment: could you provide your `nuget.config` in the OP. Also, did you try the open the `ProjectA_Common.proj` and locate the reference there like 
` <Reference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.2.0.6\lib\net45\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference> `

Comment: yes. updated the post

Comment: @Lichte What if you specify `**\*.sln` in NuGet restore task, set `system.debug` as `true`, then build and show the detail logs in one drive? Or can you share an example project which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The taks can't find any .sln files beacuse I didn't get it in the "Get Sources" task